# VS Code Keeps Updating

Tags: security, visual-studio-code, configuration, updating

VS Code keeps updating. I think it might be my workstations configuration. I have two accounts assigned to me on the domain for security. One for regular usage and a second with elevated privilege's. I login with the regular and have VS Code configured to always start as Administrator which prompts me for my second elevated user credentials.

Can this be causing the issue and what can I do to help VS Code with the update process?

Answer (score 0):

The key seems to be the shortcut to open VS Code. The properties for the shortcut showed it was opening and running in my regular login account profile directory. When I switched the shortcut to my elevated profile account the updates stopped happening every time I opened VS Code.